# Can't delete instance from two databases in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to delete an instance of a model in two databases when a user deletes it in the admin. When they create a new instance and save it, it goes to both databases. But I can't get it to delete from both databases, since the first call to delete removes the instance, so the second throws an assertion error. Is there a way to catch the instance and delete them from both databases at the same time?

```
class Change(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now = True)

    def save(self):
        super(Change, self).save(using='default')
        super(Change, self).save(using='labs')

    def delete(self):
        #Here it is deleted from the default database.
        super(Change, self).delete(using='default')
        #This doesn't work because Ive deleted the instance. How do I get this to work as well?
        super(Change, self).delete(using='labs')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the instance have the same `pk` value if the both databases?  If yes then you should restore the `pk` of the instance before deletion from the second db:

```
def delete(self):
    pk = self.pk
    super(Change, self).delete(using='default')
    self.pk = pk
    super(Change, self).delete(using='labs')
```

Comment: This works. I was doing something similar where I was setting the ID, but when I deleted it the first time it would delete my reference. I found a solution using signal, receivers and raw sql. This is far more elegant. Thanks!